# How to check if some text is present on a web page using selenium 2?

Tags: python, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am using selenium to automate test on web pages.
I am using selenium 2 and python and would like to have answers in this framework only.
SO how do I check whether some text is present or not? I have tried asset equals but it is not working?

```
assertEquals(driver.getPageSource().contains("email"), true);
```

Comment: Context is a wonderful thing here - what do you mean it doesn't work? How does it not work? What does it do? Post a copy of your HTML, just around the element you are trying to get. Why you are scanning the ENTIRE page source for that? You may need to go back to the drawing board on Selenium tutorials.

Answer (score 43):

For those of you who are still interested:

**Generic Solution**

```
if text in driver.page_source:
    # text exists in page
```

**unittest**:

```
assertTrue(text in driver.page_source)
```

**pytest**:

```
assert text in driver.page_source
```

Comment: Minor correction: the pytest one can (should) even be as simple as `assert text in driver.page_source`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've modified my answer.

Comment: Does this mean the text is "visible" or simply that it exists somewhere in the source, but perhaps hidden by css or dropdown etc?

Comment: @Jeppe it means it is just in the HTML source - so yes, it could be hidden via CSS. This issue should be considered and the solution should be tested on a page to page basis.

Comment: @ChickenFeet Thanks. "Boon kwee"s answer relies on WebDriverWait to wait for the element to be clickable - so it must be fully visible. Other wait-conditions available here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Being clickable may not mean it is visible. Having in the docs I see the method `visibility_of_element_located`, which might be a more suitable method to use. If you're waiting for an element to appear, please refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40903207/5387193).

Comment: How to detect for case insensitive comparison?

Comment: @swdev convert both search text and source text to the same case (e.g. lowercase).

Comment: @ChickenFeet I am thinking of doing that on a web page will be time consuming. I eventually using `re` like this: `if not re.search(text_to_be_found, driver.page_source, re.IGNORECASE)` Works for me

Comment: `assert "Tracking Details" in self.driver.page_source` this will not work for me. any new suggestion?

Answer (score 28):

You can use `driver.page_source` and a simple regular expression to check if the text exists:

```
import re    
src = driver.page_source
text_found = re.search(r'text_to_search', src)
self.assertNotEqual(text_found, None)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'some link text')))
```

Essentially the above lines launch Firefox, navigate to the specified url, cause the browser to hold for 10 seconds, for some url to load then look for a specific link text, if no link text is found, a TimeoutException is triggered.

Please note the number of brackets used, you will run into errors if the number of brackets does not correspond like the above.

To be able to run the above statement, the following must have been declared

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

This uses "element_to_be_clickable" - a full list of wait-conditions can be found here: [Selenium Python: Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)